# What size should the background image in an MSI be?

Tags: image, wix, windows-installer, background

I am trying to create a Windows Installer package using Wix. I'm getting a lot of conflicting information about what size my custom background should be--the Wix documentation suggests a size of 500 x 314 pixels, but this leads to slight image distortion in the installer.

I believe that I may be indirectly using the `SplashBitmap` property in Windows Installer, whose documentation suggests 480 x 320 is the correct size. When I try to use this image size, I also get artefacts in the image.

Could anyone tell me what the correct size should be?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

After a bit more searching, I found this on wixwiki.com<sup>1</sup>, whose sizes worked correctly for me (using WiX 3). They are:

- Banner: 493 x 58
- Background: 493 x 312

Hope this helps someone else, too.

<sup>1: Note: this site does not longer host WiX content.</sup>

Comment: Those are the dimensions listed in the WiX help and at http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/WixUI_customizations.htm.

Answer (score 11):

According to the [WiX online documentation](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/wixui/wixui_customizations.html) and direct measurement, the bitmap sizes are as follows:

- **WixUIBannerBmp**:   **493 × 58**
- **WixUIDialogBmp**:   **493 × 312** - image width is **164**

Comment: Image width being important, meaning you need a whole host of 'white' to the right of it or it'll stretch

Comment: Why 164, while it's mentioned 493 ?

Comment: @TarmoPikaro The width of the image on the left side of the dialog is 164. The width of the entire image, including the blank area for text on the right, is 493.

Comment: Can image somehow be aligned to left, to my best understanding image uses fill to layout horizontally ?

Answer (score 5):

According to [this WiX tutorial](https://www.firegiant.com/wix/tutorial/user-interface-revisited/legalese/) (quite a bit down towards the end of the page),  they should be:

> If you want to change the bitmaps or
>   icons, just do so in the Binary
>   directory. The front page bitmap
>   (named Dialog.bmp here) is a **503 by
>   314 pixel** BMP while the top banner
>   bitmap has **500 by 63 pixels**. But note
>   that Windows Installer might stretch
>   or shrink these bitmaps if the system
>   font and display resolution settings
>   of the user ask for a scaling of the
>   whole interface.

This [blog post](http://blogs.infosupport.com/blogs/martijnb/archive/2007/11/29/Using-WiX-UI-library.aspx) is another pretty good resource - it shows the same dimensions for the banners.

Comment: Thanks! However 503 x 314 also shows distortion with the image I'm using. I also tried changing colour depth (though I can't see what difference this would make) to no avail.

Comment: The link to the blog post returns a 403 Forbidden

Answer (score 1):

The WiX installer dialog is resized anyway depending on the system DPI setting.

On a default 100% DPI setting, the correct size is 493 x 312 as answered above. But this is unfortunately multiplied by the DPI ratio, and scaled with a crappy nearest neighbor filter.

High DPI screens become more and more popular, and need a DPI setting higher than 100% in order to stay readable. WiX installer dialogs will look crappy anyway, unfortunately.

Comment: Is there any way of supplying high resolution icons (@2x, @3x...)? The documentation doesn't seem to mention anything

Comment: Unfortunately, not in the current  version. The tool is becoming somewhat outdated

Answer (score 0):

I'm using WiX 3.7.1224 (Dec'12). By trial and error, I find that the following size is necessary to make the images fit:

```
WixUIBannerBmp: 493 × 58 (same as above)
WixUIDialogBmp: 616 × 390 (new size?)
```

There is a clear zone approx. 226 px wide on the left side of the image.